# Python PIP: Does the order in which options are specified matter?

Tags: python, pip

What is the difference between

```
$ pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

and

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
```

?

Comment: Did you try both—what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Looking at the [source](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/commands/install.py))

pip is using standard [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module which does not differ the options order, so those are the same. That's common unless a tool enforces the order with some [trick](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#callback-example-2-check-option-order), which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

doesn't matter the order, is all the same

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way to deal with comand line arguments is to use module bundled with standard python library.

And after you pass arguments, application get them and parse them in defined order (look at pip source code if it matter to you).

Some actions can be postponed after parsing, but they have strict order.

Order is not important, and both examples will always do the same (unless some error occure).